# DocuSign API SetBody Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, docusignapi

I'm trying to use a service of DocuSign API in an `objective C` project. This [link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Status%20for%20more%20than%20one%20envelope.htm?TocPath=REST%20API%20References%7C_____70) shows what data I've to add to body but I'm still starting with `objective C` development and I can't know how do it.

I tried the following but I received nil data

```
NSDictionary *EnvelopesStatusRequestData = @{@"envelopeIds": envelopesPending};
```

where `envelopesPending` is an array that I fill with envelopesId that I have in a DDBB.

```
NSMutableArray *envelopesPending = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This is the code that I use to call service API:

```
NSDictionary *authenticationHeader = @{ @"Username": email, @"Password" : password, @"IntegratorKey" : integratorKey };
NSDictionary *EnvelopesStatusRequestData = @{@"envelopeIds": envelopesPending};

NSData* dataStatus = [[self jsonStringFromObject:EnvelopesStatusRequestData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *envelopesURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/envelopes/status",baseUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *envelopeRequest = [self initializeRequest:envelopesURL setMethod:@"GET" setBody:dataStatus];
[envelopeRequest setValue:[self jsonStringFromObject:authenticationHeader] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-DocuSign-Authentication"];
[envelopeRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *envelopesResponse = nil;
NSError *envelopesError = nil;
NSData *envelopeData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:envelopeRequest returningResponse:&envelopesResponse error:&envelopesError];
```

**EDIT:**

The error was that is a PUT method, so the request is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *envelopeRequest = [self initializeRequest:envelopesURL setMethod:@"PUT" setBody:dataStatus];
```

With this change I have an error that says:

errorCode = "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER";
message = "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime, or 'envelope_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified.";

This error is solved adding the envelope_ids parameter to request:

PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?**envelope_ids=request_body**

I pass the dictionary to a string with this code:

```
NSData *dataEnv = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:envelopesPending options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

NSString *querystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataEnv encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

NSString *envelopesURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=%@",baseUrl, querystring];
```

Comment: So does that mean you've got this working now?  If so you should answer your own question so that the community benefits from this...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've figured this out, but basically here are the details of the REST API call you need to make:

---

### Get Envelope Status for more than One Envelope

This returns envelope status for the requested envelopes.

*URL*:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status
```

*Formats*:

```
XML, JSON
```

*HTTP Method*:

```
PUT
```

*Required URL Parameter*:

```
?envelope_ids=request_body
```

*Request Body*:

```
{
  "envelopeIds":[
    "String content",
    "String content"
  ],
}
```

---

So a sample request would look like:

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "envelopeIds":[
    "12af49cd-....................",
    "b342c324-...................."
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was that is a PUT method, so the request is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *envelopeRequest = [self initializeRequest:envelopesURL setMethod:@"PUT" setBody:dataStatus];
```

With this change I have an error that says:

errorCode = "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER"; message = "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime, or 'envelope_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified.";

This error is solved adding the envelope_ids parameter to request:

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body
```

I pass the dictionary to a string with this code:

```
NSData *dataEnv = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:envelopesPending options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

NSString *querystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataEnv encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
querystring = [querystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

NSString *envelopesURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=%@",baseUrl, querystring];
```